# Import data from JTable to Excel

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable

i have code to import data from JTable to Excel like this:

```
public void toExcel(JTable table, File file){
try {

        WritableWorkbook workbook1 = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);
        WritableSheet sheet1 = workbook1.createSheet("First Sheet", 0); 
        TableModel model = table.getModel();

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Label column = new Label(i, 0, model.getColumnName(i));
            sheet1.addCell(column);
        }
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                Label row = new Label(j, i + 1, 
                        model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                sheet1.addCell(row);
            }
        }
        workbook1.write();
        workbook1.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


void excell(){
          toExcel(TabelPerencanaan, new File("H:\\Hasil.xlsx"));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved at " +
                        "'H: \\ Hasil.xlsx' successfully", "Message",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

}

But, when open file "Hasil.xlsx" always error. so, that file can't opened. i don't know why like that. thanks

Comment: this error like this "Excell cannot open the file'result.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Java Excel API only generates spreadsheets in Excel 2000 format. In that case, you need:

```
new File("H:\\Hasil.xls")
```

But if you really need to generate a XLSX, you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
TableModel model = table.getModel();
for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    row.createCell(i).setCellValue(model.getColumnName(i));
}
for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
    for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        row.createCell(j).setCellValue(
            model.getValueAt(i, j).toString()
        );
    }
}
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("H:\\Hasil.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: i found error like this...
incompatible type
required : jxl.Workbook
found: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

thanks